# how to groupby column values

Tags: dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

here my data below: Dataframe -- df_AW17

```
Product ID  Season  Division    Brand   Category    Sub Category    AW16 (Sales)    AW17 (Sales)

Blazer 1    AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER      198

Blazer 2    AW16    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER  138 

Blazer 2    AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER      270

Blazer 3    AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER      27

Blazer 4    AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER      192

Blazer-10   AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      15

Blazer-11   AW16    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER  10  

Blazer-11   AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      14

Blazer-12   AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      16

Blazer-13   AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      207

Blazer-5    AW16    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER  126 

Blazer-5    AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      200

Blazer-6    AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER      5

Blazer-7    AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      299

Blazer-8    AW17    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top BLAZER      147

Blazer-9    AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top BLAZER      23

Jacket-10   AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top JACKETS     20

Jacket-11   AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top JACKETS     5

Jacket-12   AW16    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top JACKETS 5   

Jacket-12   AW17    Men's Wear  Brand 1 Top JACKETS     12

Jacket-13   AW16    Women's Wear    Brand 1 Top JACKETS 15
```

It has Product ID as value , i need to get sales growth % as new column using Season AW16, AW17 with given Sales of AW16 (Sales), AW17 (Sales). Problem is i was not able to group or put formula as columns values of Sales are in different Rows for particular Product ID.

I had tried to do.

`df_AW17['Sales Growth %'] =  df_AW17.groupby(['Product ID'])(((df_AW17['AW17 (Sales)'] - df_AW17['AW16 (Sales)']) / df_AW17['AW16 (Sales)']) * 100)`.

and result i want is (Sales growth %) from year AW16 (Sales) to AW17 (Sales) specific to Product ID.

Comment: Type Product ID Season AW16 (Sales) AW17 (Sales)
0 Fashion Blazer 1 AW17 NaN 198.0
4 Fashion Blazer 2 AW16 138.0 NaN
5 Fashion Blazer 2 AW17 NaN 270.0
7 Fashion Blazer 3 AW17 NaN 27.0
11 Fashion Blazer 4 AW17 NaN 192.0

Answer (score 0):

as all rows in your dataframe seem to have unique product ids, would the simpler following creation of a new column not fulfill the purpose?

```
df_AW17['Sales_growth_pct'] = (df_AW17['AW17 (Sales)'] - df_AW17['AW16 (Sales)']) / df_AW17['AW16 (Sales)']
```

Comment: my data in "Product" is not unique, some values been duplicated as . example : Blazer 2    AW16    sales (138) 
AW17 sales(270) . some kind of logic which can group those duplicate Product ID and get difference of sale to get actual growth %(b-a)/a*100